# Finding the limit of $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24}+\frac{1}{60}+\frac{1}{120}+...[\text{upto n times}])$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

The question is as follows-

> Evaluate the limit.
>
> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24}+\frac{1}{60}+\frac{1}{120}+...[\text{upto n times}])$$

I have no idea on how to solve this limit.

Thanks for any help,response or hint!!

Comment: What is the pattern?  What is the general term of the sum?

Comment: What is the general formula for the denominator? And do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use formula:**
$$\frac{1}{n^3-n}=\frac1{(n-1)n(n+1)}=\frac12 \left(\frac1{n(n-1)}-\frac1{n(n+1)} \right)$$

Then 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24}+\frac{1}{60}+\frac{1}{120}+...+\frac{1}{n^3-n}\right)=$$
$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac12\left(\frac{1}{2\cdot1}-\frac{1}{2\cdot3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot2}-\frac{1}{3\cdot4}+\frac{1}{4\cdot3}-...-\frac{1}{n(n+1}\right)=$$

$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac12\left(\frac12-\frac{1}{n(n+1)} \right)=\frac14$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer?I am having problem in understanding how you obtained the $\frac{1}{2}$ in the last part....

Comment: Excellent...But how did you come to know about the $\text{+  -}$ form?

Comment: If $(a_n) -$ arithmetical progression, then
$$\frac1{(a-d)a(a+d)}=\frac1d(\frac1{a(a-d)}+\frac1{a(a+d)})$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\dfrac1{n(n-1)(n+1)}=\dfrac{n+1-n}{n(n-1)(n+1)}=\dfrac1{n(n-1)}-\dfrac1{(n-1)(n+1)}$$

$$\dfrac1{n(n-1)}=\dfrac{n-(n-1)}{n(n-1)}=f(n-1)-f(n)$$

where $f(m)=\dfrac1m$

$$\dfrac2{(n-1)(n+1)}=\dfrac{n+1-(n-1)}{(n-1)(n+1)}=f(n-1)-f(n+1)$$

$$2\sum_{r=2}^n\dfrac1{r^3-r}=2\sum_{r=2}^n\left\{f(r-1)-f(r)\right\}-\sum_{r=2}^n\left\{f(r-1)-f(r+1)\right\}$$

Set a few values of $n$ to recognize the Telescoping Series.

Answer (score 0):

$$2\sum_2^{n+1}\frac{1}{(m-1)m(m+1)}=\sum_2^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{m(m-1)}-\frac{1}{(m+1)m}\right)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$ So the limit is $\frac{1}{4}$.